# Silverstripe 4 Fluent Locale Menu - How determine if page exists in actual locale?

Tags: php, fluent, silverstripe-4

```
Silverstripe 4.3 / tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent (master)
```

I would like to hide or highlight navigation entries in the `LocaleMenu.ss`. Therefore I have to figure out if there's a live version of the actual page in the actual locale. This doesn't seem to be built in.

I'm new so `SS4` and `Fluent`, had a look into some fluent methods but couldn't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Since it's only for Pages in my case I created a custom query function that I call in the template.

```
  $sqlQuery = new SQLSelect();
  $sqlQuery->setFrom('SiteTree_Localised_Live');
  $sqlQuery->addSelect('COUNT("SiteTree_Localised_Live"."ID")');
  $sqlQuery->addWhere(["RecordID" => $pageId, "Locale" => $locale]);
  $sqlQuery->setGroupBy("ID");                                        // SS throwing error with MySQL 5.7 if no Group By
  $count = $sqlQuery->execute()->value();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a page exists in a given locale by using a modified FluentState context:

```
$pageInLocale = FluentState::singleton()->withState(function (FluentState $newState) use ($pageId, $locale) {
    $newState->setLocale($locale);
    return Page::get()->byID($pageId);
});
```

If you know the locale and have a page instance already, you can also use one of these methods:

```
$page->existsInLocale($locale);      // exists in either draft or live stage
$page->isDraftedInLocale($locale);   // exists in draft stage
$page->isPublishedInLocale($locale); // exists in live stage
```